How to locate high symmetry points at k-axis in the band structure?
after band structure calculation, I got the following band structure: 
The input parameters for band calculation is
BandLineScale ReciprocalLatticeVectors
%block BandLines
1    0      0      0
200  0      0.5    0
200  0.333  0.333  0
200  0      0      0
%endblock Bandlines

I got # k_min, k_max      =     0.0000    2.2335 from freename.dat transferred from systemlabel.bands by gnubands.
I have marked the gamma point on the band structure because I only know the location of this point, which is the beginning and end of the k axis as I have specified in the %block BandLines. How to locate other high symmetry points like (0 0.5 0),(0.333,0.333,0) at k-axis in the band structure?
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Although the answer is accepted, there is a general theory that is missing from the entire condense matter books like kittel or mermin. In this paper they have provided the theory to obtain the high symmetry points of any crystal structure (don't worry about the other parts in the paper just read the theory): https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0927025610002697

The band structure in the question comes from a 2d hexagonal structure, I will take it as an example
In the picture below,the white lines are the crystal structure, the blue area is the first Brillouin zone, the dark blue lines are the reciprocal lattice, g1, g2 and g3 are the basis vectors of the reciprocal lattice, and the dark balls are atoms.
The high symmetry points are gamma(0,0,0),F(0,0.5,0),E(0.333,0.333,0).
The path formed by the high symmetry points forms a right-angled triangle has one angle size 60 degrees.
The ratio of each side length of this triangle to the perimeter of the triangle is the ratio of each high symmetry point on the k axis.
That is to say，F(0,0.5,0) should locate at $\sqrt{3}$/($\sqrt{3}$+1+2)$\approx$0.366 and E(0.333,0.333,0) at ($\sqrt{3}$+1)/($\sqrt{3}$+1+2)$\approx$0.578 assuming that the total length of the k-axis is 1.


Commonly the highsymmetry points that you call E and F are called K and M.

xinbiaos answer is factually correct (and well put), but I am unsure it directly answers your question. I believe you are asking where on the x-axis of the plot are you placing the labels to your high symmetry k-path.
A band structure is taking the energies at each kpoint and placing them side by side - so it's like unrolling this path and placing it on single axis. What helps is that your input file gives you some clues. The most important clue is that each path (going from one high symmetry point to another) has a definite number of points along it.
In your case
1    0      0      0 start at gamma (point 0)
200  0      0.5    0 take 200 steps along x
200  0.333  0.333  0 take another 200 steps along x
200  0      0      0 end here

So you know that each high symmetry point on your plot is separated by 200 points. So the labels should be placed on x=0, x=200, x=400, and so on.
